# dismiss UINavigationController interactive

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, transition

I am trying to interactively dismiss a UINavigationController with on UIViewController on its stack

i. I present as follow:

```
UIViewController *vc = [UIViewController new];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRoot:vc];
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

ii.. In my ViewController I have set  in the .h file. In the .m file I set `self.transitioningDelegate.self` I also tried `self.navigationController.transitioningDelegate = self`

iii. Finally I implement the delegate methods:

```
#pragma mark - ViewControllerTransitioning Delegate Methods
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)
animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented
presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting
sourceController:(UIViewController *)source {
    NSLog(@"\n\nTRANSIT 1\n\n");
    // allow the interaction controller to wire-up its gesture recognisers
    [_interactionController wireToViewController:presented
                                    forOperation:CEInteractionOperationDismiss];
    _animationController.reverse = NO;
    return _animationController;
}

- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)
animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed {
    NSLog(@"\n\nTRANSIT 2\n\n");
    _animationController.reverse = YES;
    return _animationController;
}

- (id<UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning>)
interactionControllerForDismissal:
(id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animator {
    NSLog(@"\n\nTRANSIT 3\n\n");
    // provide the interaction controller, if an interactive transition is in progress
    return _interactionController.interactionInProgress
    ? _interactionController : nil;
}
```

iv. The interactive part is never executed when unfortunately. When I manually hit a button that calls `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Both the Transit 2 and Transit 3 are printed, but the Transit 1 is never reached. Does anybody has any suggestions what this might be? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` instead of `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`. I guess that.

Comment: that unfortunately won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Finally solved this. The problem is that at the moment of presenting a new `UIViewController` using : `UINavigationController *n = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRoot:yourVC]
  [self presentViewController:n animated:YES completion:nil];`

the current presenting ViewController will look in `n` for transitioningDelegate methods, specifically:

```
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)
animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented
presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting
sourceController:(UIViewController *)source {
    NSLog(@"\n\nTRANSIT 1\n\n");
    // allow the interaction controller to wire-up its gesture recognisers
    [_interactionController wireToViewController:presented
                                    forOperation:CEInteractionOperationDismiss];
    _animationController.reverse = NO;
    return _animationController;
}
```

which is used to wire up the interactionController's gesture recognizer is not called. Hence, to circumvent this issue, we must call the following in the ViewController's to be presented viewDidLoad:

```
[_interactionController wireToViewController:self forOperation:CEInteractionOperationDismiss];
```

This way the viewController will be wired up and good to go. The only outstanding issue is that the translation in view seems to be increased by 5x - any suggestions as to why this might be are appreciated!